# Calculating area or counting number of pixels by category using Python

Tags: python, raster, pixel, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to count the number of pixels and calculate the area of each category in 5 images. The categories are 1,2,or 3 in three of the images and UP and P in two of the images.

How do you calculate area by category for raster images in Python?

I have tried...

```
areas = scen1classG.reduceRegion(**{
  'reducer': ee.Reducer.sum().group(),
  'geometry': PAshp,
  'scale': 30,
  'maxPixels': 1e9
})
print(areas)
```

I have also tried

```
sums = scen1classG.reduceRegion({
    'selectors': ['1', '2', '3'],
    'reducer': ee.Reducer.sum().repeat(2).group({
      'groupField': 2,
      'groupName': 'Result',
    })
});
print(sums);
```

And

```
areaImage = scen1classG.pixelArea().divide(1e6).addBands('Results');

areas = areaImage.reduceRegion({
      'reducer': ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      'groupField': 1,
      'groupName': 'Results',
    }),
    'geometry': PAshp,
    'scale': 30,
    #tileScale: 4,
    'maxPixels': 1e9
    }); 

var classAreas = ee.List(areas.get('groups'))
print(classAreas)
```

Here is the relevant code with one of my failed attempts.

```
# Load U.S. state of interest.
PAshp = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2018/States').filter(ee.Filter.eq('STUSPS', 'PA'))
# Load corn areas.
CDL13=ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL').filter(ee.Filter.date('2013-01-01', '2013-12-31')).filterBounds(PAshp).select('cropland').first();
crop_corn13 = CDL13.updateMask(CDL13.eq(1)).clip(PAshp);
# Load LANDSAT8 NDVI. 
l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI");
l8_13=l8.filterDate('2013-06-15', '2013-07-15').filterBounds(PAshp).mosaic().updateMask(crop_corn13)
#Select NDVI
ndvi13=l8_13.select('NDVI');
GY13 = ndvi13.multiply(3.00).exp().multiply(0.71);
CL13G = 9.43;
factor13G = CL13G/5.445561801776144;
GY13_adj=GY13.multiply(factor13G);
CLallyearsG = 9.0175;
# Grain. 
#Create an image collection of adjusted modeled grain yield (GY).
ColG = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([ee.Image(GY13_adj),ee.Image(GY14_adj),ee.Image(GY15_adj),ee.Image(GY16_adj),ee.Image(GY17_adj),ee.Image(GY18_adj),ee.Image(GY19_adj),ee.Image(GY20_adj)]);
#Mosaic grain yield.
mosaicG = ColG.mosaic();
#Calculate the mean of GY across years for each pixel. 
mG = ColG.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
#Calculate the standard deviation of GY across years for each pixel.
sdG = ColG.reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev());
#Set standard deviation threshold. 
sdGthreshold = 10;
scen1classG = sdG.where(sdG.gt(sdGthreshold),1) \
                 .where(sdG.lte(sdGthreshold).And(mG.lt(CLallyearsG)),2) \
                 .where(sdG.lte(sdGthreshold).And(mG.gte(CLallyearsG)),3) \
                 .rename('Result') 
areaImage = scen1classG.pixelArea().divide(1e6).addBands('Results');

areas = areaImage.reduceRegion({
      'reducer': ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      'groupField': 1,
      'groupName': 'Results',
    }),
    'geometry': PAshp,
    'scale': 30,
    #tileScale: 4,
    'maxPixels': 1e9
    }); 

var classAreas = ee.List(areas.get('groups'))
print(classAreas)
```

Comment: I tried to have a look but got an error while opening your notebook

Comment: Thanks, PGerrits. I updated the link in the question. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Still receiving "Notebook loading error. There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.". Perhaps it is my computer/browser.

Comment: Hmm, I am looking into it. I think the solution may be something like this, though I think I need to specifiy the groups.        areas = scen1classG.reduceRegion(**{
  'reducer': ee.Reducer.sum().group(),
  'geometry': PAshp,
  'scale': 30,
  'maxPixels': 1e9
})
print(areas)

Comment: I also added some code above if the link does not. Thank you!

Comment: That notebook link requires a Google account to view. Please reduce the code to just the relevant parts and post them right here in the question.

Comment: Thank you @bugmenot123 for your attempt. I have updated the question with the relevant code and what I have attempted. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @PGerrits for your attempts. I have updated the question with the relevant code and what I have attempted. Thanks!

Comment: @Sam Thanks for the updates. Not sure if you managed yet but have you had a look at the Zonal Histogram tool from QGIS/GDAL? It basically does what you intend to do.

Comment: As per [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.